# pivot table in excel shows up as 1 in the data field. When I try and change the 'summarise data by' to sum it comes up as 0,

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2007

I am trying to insert the pivot table in excel,
This shows up as 1 in the data field. When I try and change the 'summarise data by' to sum it comes up as 0, and when i try to summarise by average i get #DIV/0!

Comment: That means that your data field is text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.